# Else statement counter within function

Tags: python, rhino3d

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

def conCir(pt, r):
    if r <= 0:
        print "Done"
    else:
        rs.AddCircle(pt, r)
        return conCir(pt, r-1)

pt1 = rs.GetPoint("Pick First Point")
pt2 = rs.GetPoint("Pick Second Point")
r = rs.Distance(pt1, pt2)
conCir(pt1, r)
```

What I try is to make concentric circles, however, I can't figure out how to count the number of circles created. In an ideal situation, this counter is embedded within the function, but placing it on the first line makes it reset to 0 every time the function is called.

To be clear, when finished the function needs to print "Done", count, "circles were drawn."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a counter in the recursive call, and print it when printing `Done`

```
def conCir(pt, r, count=0):
    if r <= 0:
        print "Done"
        print count, " circles were drawn"
    else:
        rs.AddCircle(pt, r)
        return conCir(pt, r-1, count+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use the variable 'count' in the if-statement, because it will say that it isn't defined?

Answer (score 0):

same as Barmar's answer, expanded debug printing

Python 3 print()

just printing instead of calling Circle for illustration

added default var `count = 0` for the recursion

```
def conCir(pt, r, count = 0):
    if r <= 0:
        print("Done", 'count= ', count)
    else:
        print('AddinCircle ',pt, r) # rs.AddCircle(pt, r)
        return conCir(pt, r-1, count + 1)

conCir('fred', 5) # count default = 0, no need to enter in call

AddinCircle  fred 5
AddinCircle  fred 4
AddinCircle  fred 3
AddinCircle  fred 2
AddinCircle  fred 1
Done count=  5
```